# Error due to unexpected value in module when use command "ionic cordova build android --release --prod"

Tags: ionic4

I tried to do ionic cordova build android --release --prod but this error come out.

***ERROR in : Unexpected value 'ServicePage in C:/Users/User/Ionic project/PLUMS/src/app/service/service.page.ts' declared by the module 'ServicePageModule in C:/Users/User/Ionic project/PLUMS/src/app/service/service.module.ts'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.***

What should I do to solve the error?

```
**code for service.module.ts**
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ServicePage } from './service.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ServicePage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [ServicePage]
})
export class ServicePageModule {}
```

```
**code for service.page.ts**
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-service',
  templateUrl: './service.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./service.page.scss'],
})

export class ServicePage {
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this :

```
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
```

this is for injecting service/providers .And you are showing page

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
@IonicPage()
```

because ServicePage is a page and you don't forget add the import for this annotation. Apart of that, you need to remove

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})
```

because that annotation is for services.

Regards!